# Parsing JSON stream

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, stream, google-chrome-app

I have an application that is using `chrome.sockets`. JSON is being passed to and from the socket which does not have a delimiter and is not prefixed with the length of the string.

Now the way sockets are read in `chrome.sockets` is by passing a max buffer length and it will read all available bytes until the buffer is full. The documentation for the `socket.read` can be found [here](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/socket.html#method-read)

Short of writing/porting a parser, is there a JavaScript JSON parser where I can simply pipe in the response from `socket.read`?

Answer (score 0):

Update: As you need to check that the JS is valid, you could use JSON.parse to check if it's valid JSON, this should always be available in Chrome. You can convert your arraybuffer to a string and append it on to an accumulator string and after each iteration perform the following check on that string.

```
function isValidJSON(str) {
    try {
        JSON.parse(str);
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
};


// assuming 16bit uint unicode chars
function ab2str(buf) {
   return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(buf));
}
```

Below is an example callback function you could use:

```
jsonData = "";
function readJSONFromSocket(object readInfo) {

    // Arraybuffer to string
    partialJSONData = ab2str(readInfo.data);
    // Loop through the chars until we get a valid JSON object
    for (var x = 0; x < partialJSONData.length; x++) {
        // Build up the JSON character by character
        jsonData += partialJSONData.charAt(x);
        if (isValidJSON(jsonData)) {
            console.log(jsonData);
            // Do something here
            jsonData = "";
        }
    }       
};
```

Comment: I think you may have missed a trick. The `readInfo.data` is of type `ArrayBuffer`, which is simply an array of bytes. You first need to convert this to text using whatever encoding, and then convert to a JSON object...the problem I have is knowing when I have a complete JSON object string, hence the need for a parser.

Comment: Ok, once you have converted to a string you could use the function I added in the update to check if it's valid, it should be invalid until you've received the entire object.

Comment: ...but this comes back to the whole problem I was talking about in the OP...how do I know when I have a full object. In the first buffer I could get `{.....` and in the second buffer i get `..}{...}{...`. I am not able to pull out one full object...without a parser, which brings us back to the original question.

Comment: Ok, I've still not done the conversion from arraybuffer to string. Not sure what the encoding is.

Comment: see here: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/06/How-to-convert-ArrayBuffer-to-and-from-String

Comment: Your latest update, the last bit where you append the partialJSONData will not work...for the reason listed in the 3rd comment

Comment: It will still be a valid string, although it will only execute the body of the conditional if it is valid JSON. Do you agree? Also, I'm assuming 16bit uint unicode chars.

Comment: On first run of that loop I get this: `{data:"som` (not valid json), on second iteration of that look I get `ething"}{da` so I concat them: `{data:"something"}{da` (this isn't valid json either)..do you get my drift? At no point can you ensure that you will get a single full json object into `jsonData`. I am guessing you are testing by sending one object down the socket...try sending multiple objects of differing length.

Comment: Ok, think that should solve it, I'm not actually testing any of this btw. I'm just making it up as I go along, I'm slightly surprised it even compiles! Anyway, looping through the chars until we have a valid JSON object will hopefully solve this. I can't help for much longer though as I have an exam tomorrow.

Comment: That is "a" solution that would work, but not the solution I am after (it would be way to slow for what I am after), thank you very much for your help. Please concentrate on your exam, and good luck!!

Comment: If you want it to be faster then use a delimiter between JSON objects and then split it into objects using that. Anyway, best of luck to yourself as well!

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen https://github.com/creationix/jsonparse? Looks like it assumes a Node.js environment, but it doesn't like it would be hard to tweak the API to meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was posted a while ago but here is a good way to handle this.

Install Node JS, install NPM (Node Package Manager)

```
npm install -g browserify
npm install -g JSONStream

echo "window.JSONStream = require('JSONStream');" > script.js

browserify script.js jsonstream.js
```

in your webpage

```
var parseStream = new JSONStream('*');

while (var buffer = socket.read()) {
  parseStream.write(buffer);
}

parseStream.on('data', function (obj) {
  // obj is a parsed obj
})
```

Now if you want pipe methodology because your a fan of unix. then add

```
npm install shoe

shoe('./socketName').pipe(parseStream);
```